# Simple AS3 - Mouse Click, spawn a movieClip on stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, movieclip

so any help would be appreciated. How would i go about setting up so a movieClip appears on the stage when a button is clicked?

```
sppawner_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spawnspinkjewel);

function spawnspinkjewel(event:MouseEvent):void
{
//------ ummmm 
}
```

thanks, I am new to AS3! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [addChild](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/states/AddChild.html) methos to add an element to stage.

```
 sppawner_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spawnspinkjewel);

    function spawnspinkjewel(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
      var myChild:MC= new MC();
      stage.addChild(myMC)
    }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping. Although your script is spitting back some errors. 

1046 : type was not found and was not a compile time constant
1180 : Call to a possible undefined method pinkjewelmc

     spawner_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spawnspinkjewel);

      function spawnspinkjewel(event:MouseEvent):void
         {
          var myChild:pink_jewel_mc= new pink_jewel_mc();
          stage.addChild(pink_jewel_mc)
         }

Any tips?

Cheers,

Comment: what pink_jewel_mc() refers to in your code? It should be the export identifier of your movieclip

Comment: Hello thanks for you help. I got it to work eventually with a bit of tinkering, although now I have run into another problem.
Also found this link to offer an additional bit of help.
http://www.danfergusdesign.com/classfiles/oldClasses/VCB331-richMedia1/exercises/addingChildren.php